# don't reset the input in a formular field using JSP

Tags: jsp

I'm practising a bit on JSP and want to create a simple formular field. The code below is working properly. Now i want that the last input stays in the formular fields. So when i type in a value "password" and a "name" both values should stay in the formular field no matter what the result of the if-else statement is.
 For example i type in "user" and "1234" and press submit the formular fields get cleared and i don't want that. The two values shall stay there after submitting. Sincerly i have no good idea how to solve this problem.
 My suggestion would be to use application.setAttribute("",) and application.getAttribute(""), but i don't know how. I would be glad for any advise. Thank you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de">

<head>
  <title>Practice</title>
</head>

<body>

<h2>Practice</h2>
<h3>Please enter your name and the password.</h3>
<form method="post" action="">
  <table>
<tr><td style="text-align:center">Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" size="80" /></td>
</tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:center">Password</td>
<td><input type="text" name="password" size="80" /></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Send" /></td>
<td><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<%-- Testing name and password. --%>
<% String name = request.getParameter("name");
   String password = request.getParameter("password");
   if (name != null && name.equals("user") && password != null && password.equals("1234"))
     {
%>
       <p>Your Input is correct!</p>
<%   }

   else
     {
%>
       <p>Your input is not correct!</p>
<%   }
%>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fill their `value` attribute with the submitted value. In *normal* JSP EL that would be:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
...
<input type="text" name="username" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.username)}" />
<input type="password" name="password" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.password)}" />
```

The `${param.username}` does basically the same as the following ugly *scriptlet* `<% if (request.getParameter("username") != null) { out.print(request.getParameter("username")); } %>`, only in a much more clean and consice way.

The JSTL `fn:escapeXml()` function is there to prevent you from [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) [attacks](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html). Otherwise users would be able to enter `"><script>alert('xss');</script>` as name and get it executed (of course with a more malicious javascript which sends the cookies to another server for example instead of a simple alert).

Comment: That's a really simple and good solution. Thank you very much.